# How to test a microsoft conitive services computer vsion api?

Tags: computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

I am new to azure conitive service [computer vision api](https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fa) . i wanna test analyse api on microsft  console itself. I am trying to extract image description from api. When ever i  past the image url it gtes striked off and changed to red color. the site says the url is invalid. i tried with multiple images. it shows the same error. i even tried with the image url that microsft itself usin for the computer vision demo. plz help me

URL where i am testin the api services : https://centralindia.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fa/console

sample image url :

https://azurecomcdn.azureedge.net/cvt-99139de686aeb419fc63b353ae8c79ee0e1a1ef16d4d7803228d1ea648376d26/images/shared/cognitive-services-demos/analyze-image/analyze-8-thumbnail.jpg

Response i am getting

```
apim-request-id: ecb54c47-8a6e-4f16-a44f-0a40dc29e44d
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-content-type-options: nosniff
Date: Sun, 02 Jun 2019 11:45:53 GMT
Content-Length: 104
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
  "code": "BadArgument",
  "requestId": "ecb54c47-8a6e-4f16-a44f-0a40dc29e44d",
  "message": "JSON format error."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that you're hitting the proper endpoint, and that the service is expecting a proper JSON payload, but that the JSON you provided is somehow malformed.  If you're testing using the console, make sure your payload looks like the following:

```
{"url":"https://azurecomcdn.azureedge.net/cvt-99139de686aeb419fc63b353ae8c79ee0e1a1ef16d4d7803228d1ea648376d26/images/shared/cognitive-services-demos/analyze-image/analyze-8-thumbnail.jpg"}
```